# How can Ruby tell the difference between variables and method names if they have the same scope?

Tags: ruby

How can Ruby tell the difference between variables and methods if both have the same name and the same scope?

Given the scenario:

```
def something 
"33"
end

something = "44"

something # --> calling something (variable or method?)
```

I am confused because both are called with something. My question is two part:

A) Which would win out: variable or method and why?

B) Is there some way for Ruby to distinguish between the two so you can call something (the variable) and something (the method)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

variable would be first, but you can call method:

```
def foo
   33
end

foo = 44

>foo
#=> 44
>foo() #also you can call it by: self.foo || My omission, thanks @CarySwoveland

#=> 33
```

On question

> why?

@SergioTulentsev gave a good answer:

> local variable has priority over bracketless method call because otherwise it wouldn't be possible to refer to the variable

Also, for more information about methods and variables you can read [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods)

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @the12 local variable has priority over bracketless method call because otherwise it wouldn't be possible to refer to the variable.

Comment: @the12 in addition to Sergio Tulentsev you can read [this docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Local+Variables+and+Methods) it's should be more informative

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Alex, you may wish to add `self.foo #=> 33`. I prefer `self.` to `()` as I think it the former better conveys the message that what you have added to `foo` is necessary. I suggest you also add @Sergio's explanation to the answer and remove the greater-than characters. In keeping with the "keep answers clean" movement, the attribution to Sergio is better in the comments (as you have  it) than in the answer.